# How to implement in-app screenshot in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How can I implement the in-app screenshot functionality in flutter android?
I need this function to take a screenshot of the app screen and share the picture.
are there any plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have shared an example of code where I have used [Screenshot plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) available on pub.dev along with permission handler and path provider plugin. Basically this plugin wraps your widgets inside RenderRepaintBoundary and creates an screenshot of your widget.

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Screenshot Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  File _imageFile;

  //Create an instance of ScreenshotController
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _requestPermission();
  }

  _requestPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();

    final info = statuses[Permission.storage].toString();
    print(info);
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Screenshot(
                controller: screenshotController,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'You have pushed the button this many times:' +
                          _counter.toString(),
                    ),
                    FlutterLogo(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              _imageFile != null ? Image.file(_imageFile) : Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          _incrementCounter();
          _imageFile = null;

          screenshotController
              .capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10))
              .then((File image) async {
            //print("Capture Done");
            setState(() {
              _imageFile = image;
            });
            final result =
                await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image.readAsBytesSync());
            print("File Saved to Gallery $result");
          }).catchError((onError) {
            print("Error: $onError");
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  _saved(File image) async {
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image.readAsBytesSync());
    print("File Saved to Gallery");
  }
}
```

Packages used:

```
  screenshot:
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.1.0
  permission_handler:
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
```

You will need to specify storage permissions in AndroidManifest file as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To take screenshots within flutter app of the current use this [screenshot package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) it also has example and documentation for saving the image to a folder and as well as to gallery which can also be google photos using 2 other plugins which you can find there only. I have used this plugin and it works really well if you havep any queries then you can comment below. Hope this helps you out!